# parallel, exactly same rename operations on NFS succeeds

Tags: java, parallel-processing, nfs

Is it possible that multiple parallel rename operations of the same file to the same other name on NFS succeeds? This is what I experience.

I implemented file processors that work in parallel. They process files, by first "reserving" the file. The reservation is implemented via rename - adding some fixed prefix (e.g. RESERVED_, same for all processors). Only after successful reservation, they start processing the file. In this implementation I assumed that rename will succeed in only one processor. Unfortunately, what I experience is that rename succeeds in multiple processors...

More details:

- Processors are implemented in Java. I use the call File::renameTo.
- Processors work on separate servers.
- time is synced with NFS via NTP.
- I avoid FS-specific implementation (like using fcntl locks), because I wanted the same logic to work also for FTP/SFTP.

Does anyone know what is the expected behavior? Is there something I'm doing wrong or an easy fix (maybe some mounting option)? If this approach is just wrong, do you know of other approaches to generic file-locking on NFS?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Maybe try disabling the attribute cache and local locking using `no_ac` and `local_lock=none` mount options.